# Remove unwanted tags from XML file

Tags: python, python-3.x, scala, xml-parsing

I working on a XML file that contains soap tags in it. I want to remove those soap tags as part of XML cleanup process.

How can I achieve it in either Python or Scala. Should not use shell script.

**Sample Input :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://sample.com/">
   <soap:Body>
      <com:RESPONSE xmlns:com="http://sample.com/">
         <Student>
            <StudentID>100234</StudentID>
            <Gender>Male</Gender>
            <Surname>Robert</Surname>
            <Firstname>Mathews</Firstname>
         </Student>
      </com:RESPONSE>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Expected Output :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <com:RESPONSE xmlns:com="http://sample.com/">
         <Student>
            <StudentID>100234</StudentID>
            <Gender>Male</Gender>
            <Surname>Robert</Surname>
            <Firstname>Mathews</Firstname>
         </Student>
      </com:RESPONSE>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help you!

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse('test.xml')
for ele in doc.xpath('//soap'):
    parent = ele.getparent()
    parent.remove(ele)
print(etree.tostring(doc))
```